# Definir portas específicas para cada banco de dados em SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

Aqui na empresa, temos um servidor dedicado e hospedado em um datacenter que mantém inúmeros bancos de dados usando o SQLServer. Estes bancos de dados, por padrão estão trabalhando a partir da porta 1433 onde a mesma já está aberta para os clientes.

Hoje, estou tendo dificuldades em relação a velocidade de conexão de algumas pessoas, e em horários de pico de trabalho mas, meu servidor mesmo nesses horários não chega nem a metade da capacidade que ele suporta tanto de processamento, hd(ssd), quanto de memória.

Partindo disso eu creio que o problema possa estar nos roteadores (ou no lado do cliente ou no lado do meu servidor). No lado do cliente, já fizemos testes de remoção de firewall, instanciar em modo bridge e inserir outro roteador, etc... mas no lado do servidor ainda procuro opções para melhorar o desempenho.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de eu definir uma porta específica para cada banco de dados, assim eu poderia fazer com que cada cliente acessasse sua porta e (em tese) reduzir a carga do tráfego de dados para servidor e do firewall no roteador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode acessar Banco de Dados por Porta especifica. Você pode acessar Instâncias. 
Instância é a instalação do SQL Server propriamente dita e você pode ter mais de uma na mesma máquina.
Quando existem múltiplas instâncias SQL Server numa rede se faz necessário deixar iniciado o serviço `SQL Browser` que é instalado junto do SQL Server.

Se seu problema está na rede, não a nada que você possa fazer através do SQL Server.

Comment: ok. até então entendi. sendo assim se eu gerar instancias para cada base de dados eu posso então definir uma porta específica para cada uma, portanto isso resolve meu problema... isso sem contar que as filas de processamento também são por instâncias rs, valeu parceiro pela idéia

Comment: Lembrando que para você instalar várias instâncias em um mesma máquina você terá que atribuir um nome a cada uma delas (Instâncias Nomeada). Isso afetará a string de conexão dos sistemas. Lembrar também de distribuir os recursos da maquina entre as instâncias (Memória e CPU)

Comment: sim, até certo ponto fica até melhor do que ter somente uma instancia. isso porque tenho clientes grandes e pequenos no mesmo servidor e o fluxo deles mudam.